# Browser not displaying base64 images

Tags: c#, base64

[image: Original image added for reference]I want to display images on browser by converting them to base64 string.
Method of conversion is very simple as follows

```
string convertedfile = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData);
```

base64 string

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,DQoaCgAAAA1JSERSAAAAFAAAABQIBgAAAI2JHQ0AAAABc1JHQgCuzhzpAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAAl2cEFnAAAAgAAAAIAAMOExmgAAAAZiS0dEAAAAAAAA+UO7fwAAACJ6VFh0U29mdHdhcmUAAHjaKy8v18vMyy5OTixI1csvSgcANtgGWBBTylwAAADzSURBVDhPY/wPBAxUBExUNAts1KiBlIfoaBhiD8N1NycwHLi/mqgAJhiGp15uYtj1aCbD5OMZDDdenSJsKCjr4QJvfzz977GZAS5t2Mvw//P3j/i0/EeoRlP299/v/667UaX//vv7X6MOpxawCThlw04z/H//8zmGa158fPDfsBq3oYzYSpusW8IMPgJVDEa8gQxff31k+P8PaPE/Bob/fxkYuNkEGfZeXskwZ1cnw6Hm9xhhimHgn/8/Gea9SGP485OR4fu37wx/fzIw/PkBwTA2818OIP8fQ0P4XAY2FjYUQ7G6kHBU4lZBMNmQavjgNxAArnYq4oN7ItkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Original File"/>
```

For some reason my browser is not able to display it. Is there any MIME type I have to set in IIS? or what could be the problem?

**Edit:**
To write file data to SQL

```
          Stream fs = imgUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                //string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                //imgPicture.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString());
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbEHUsers set photo=@binaryValue where UserID=101", conn))
                {
                    // Replace 8000, below, with the correct size of the field
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@binaryValue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = bytes;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
```

My method to get image data from SQL(column datatype varbinary)

```
    byte[] fileData =null;
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = CMD.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
        {
            if (rdr.Read())
            {

                // For some reason the data being returned is blank
                // When I run it in SQL I get data being returned.

                 fileData = (byte[])rdr.GetValue(0);

                using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("D:\\Testing.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs))
                    {
                        bw.Write(fileData);
                        bw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            rdr.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I don't think your string is valid. Try using this site: http://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: you are right...but what could be the ereason for getting wrong string?...I have also edited by question

Comment: The code for writing the data to the file looks ok. (Using a `BinaryWriter` to write bytes to a file is overkill, but it works.) How do you read the data from the file?

Comment: @Guffa question edited please check...

Comment: @Tweety01: I can't spot any error there. You should check if you have the correct data before writing it to the data, and after you have read it back from the database. You can verify that the first four bytes are `255, 216, 255, 224`.

Answer (score 4):

The data that you have isn't a PNG image at all. Exchange it for a real PNG image, and it will work.

Example, a 10x10 red square:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAXSURBVChTY/jPwPCfGDyqEC+mtkKG/wCSw8c5Wcde4gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

Here is your original image in base64 form:

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Having a + in the src attribute will not cause a problem for base64 strings. Please remove comment (i.e. Server.UrlEncode not required).

Comment: @Cal279: Thanks, you are right. I added an example of a working image instead.

Comment: @Tweety01: If it's supposed to be a JPEG image, then the eight first bytes (or more) are missing.